# creating gradient/rainbow strokeStyle html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm having fun playing around with HTML5 canvas. So far I have this cool drawing app and I would like the stroke style to be a gradient of different colors. How would I go about doing that? Here is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/4kt38/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//puts a circle where the user clicks the mouse

var radius = 10,
dragging = false;

context.lineWidth = radius*2;

var putPoint = function(e){
if(dragging){
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   }
};

var engage = function(e){
dragging = true;
putPoint(e);
};

var disengage = function(){
dragging = false;
context.beginPath();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `context.fillStyle = grad;`  after:

```
var grad= context.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
grad.addColorStop(0, "red");
grad.addColorStop(1, "green");
context.fillStyle = grad;
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, but the stroke comes out like little half circles instead. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/4kt38/4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really happy with this quick effort, but here's a starting attempt at a rainbow-gradient stroke.

This code just grabs the dragging mouse position and strokes along the drag.

An improvement to this code would be to simplify the path rather than grabbing every mousemove.

It works by drawing a large number of linear gradient lines perpendicular to the desired path.  This fools the eye into thinking it sees a gradient stroke.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/36F4T/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    var PI=Math.PI;
    var points=[];
    var isDown=false;
    var linewidth=15;
    var steps=50;
    var lastPointX,lastPointY;

    ctx.lineWidth=linewidth;

    function addPoint(x,y){
        var dx=x-lastPointX;
        var dy=y-lastPointY;
        var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx)-PI/2;

        ctx.strokeStyle=calcGradient(x,y,angle);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPointX,lastPointY);
        for(var i=-8;i<steps;i++){
            var xx=lastPointX+dx*i/(steps-1);
            var yy=lastPointY+dy*i/(steps-1);
            ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
        }
        ctx.stroke();

        lastPointX=x;
        lastPointY=y;
    }

    function calcGradient(x,y,angle){
        // calc the topside and bottomside points of the tangent line
        var offX1=x+linewidth/2.25*Math.cos(angle);
        var offY1=y+linewidth/2.25*Math.sin(angle);
        var offX2=x+linewidth/2.25*Math.cos(angle-PI);
        var offY2=y+linewidth/2.25*Math.sin(angle-PI);
        // create a gradient stretching between 
        // the calculated top & bottom points
        var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(offX1,offY1,offX2,offY2);
        gradient.addColorStop(0.00, 'red'); 
        gradient.addColorStop(1/6, 'orange'); 
        gradient.addColorStop(2/6, 'yellow'); 
        gradient.addColorStop(3/6, 'green') 
        gradient.addColorStop(4/6, 'aqua'); 
        gradient.addColorStop(5/6, 'blue'); 
        gradient.addColorStop(1.00, 'purple'); 
        return(gradient);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      lastPointX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      lastPointY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      addPoint(mouseX,mouseY);

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```